# TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to learn python in chp.3 but I have a problem.
Can someone help me?

```
import urllib.request
import time

def send_to_twitter(msg):

password_manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgr()
password_manager.add_password("Twitter API",
                              "http://twitter.com/statuses","xxx","xxx")
http_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
page_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(http_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(page_opener)
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'status': msg})
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json", params)
resp.read()

def get_price():

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans-r-us.appspot.com/prices.html")
text = page.read().decode("utf8")
where = text.find('>$')
start_of_price = where + 2
end_of_price = start_of_price + 4

return float (text[start_of_price:end_of_price])


price_now = input("Do you want to see the price now(Y/N)? ")

if price_now =="Y":

        send_to_twitter(get_price())
else:
            price=99.99

        while price > 4.74:

          time.sleep(900)

          price = get_price()

        send_to_twitter("Buy")
```

But can't run.

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file
>   object. It cannot be of type str.

Comment: Please make sure your formatting is correct prior to posting

Comment: The error message is quite helpfull if you ask me. You defined an object as the wrong type.